# Saving throws against Destroyer weapons

Tags: warhammer-40k

If your opponent hits one of your models with a D strength weapon, rolls on the table and gets a 'Seriously Wounded' result, then rolls 3 for the number of wounds. How many saving throws do I roll? Is it 1 save for the 1 hit or 3 saves for each of the 3 wounds?

Answer (score 3):

You roll one save against the D hit. That one hit does D3 wounds - it doesn't do D3 hits.